# UIImage cv::Mat conversions with alpha channel

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

I'm using following codes for converting `UIImage*` and `cv::Mat` to each other:

```
- (cv::Mat)cvMatFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image
{
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
  CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
  CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

  cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels (color channels + alpha)

  CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to  data
                                                 cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                 rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                 8,                          // Bits per component
                                                 cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                 colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                 kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

  CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
  CGContextRelease(contextRef);

  return cvMat;
}
```

and

```
-(UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
  CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

  if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
      colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
  } else {
      colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  }

  CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

  // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
  CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 //width
                                     cvMat.rows,                                 //height
                                     8,                                          //bits per component
                                     8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       //bits per pixel
                                     cvMat.step[0],                            //bytesPerRow
                                     colorSpace,                                 //colorspace
                                     kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                     provider,                                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                     NULL,                                       //decode
                                     false,                                      //should interpolate
                                     kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   //intent
                                     );


  // Getting UIImage from CGImage
  UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
  CGImageRelease(imageRef);
  CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
  CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

  return finalImage;
 }
```

I took these from [OpenCV Documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html). I use them as follows:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent.png"];
UIImage *img2 = [self UIImageFromCVMat:[self cvMatFromUIImage:img]];
```

However these functions loses the alpha channel information. I know it is because of the flags `kCGImageAlphaNone` and `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast`, unfortunately I could't find a way not lose alpha information by changing these flags.

So, how do I convert these two types between each other without losing alpha information?

Here is the image that I use:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We should use these functions from opencv v2.4.6:

```
UIImage* MatToUIImage(const cv::Mat& image);
void UIImageToMat(const UIImage* image, cv::Mat& m, bool alphaExist = false);
```

And don't forget to include:

```
opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to not pass `kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast` and instead pass `(kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst)` to get premultiplied alpha in BGRA format. CoreGraphics only supports premultiplied alpha. But, you will need to check on how OpenCV represents alpha in pixels to determine how to tell OpenCV that the pixels are already premultiplied. The code I have used assumes straight alpha with OpenCV, so you will need to be careful of that.